# How to combine fields of objects by a certain attribute?

Tags: kotlin

I need to filter these `Person` objects by `name`, then count the number of `Device`s for each unique `name`.

```kotlin
data class Device(val name: String, val price: Int)
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int, val devices: List<Device>)
data class PersonFinal(val name: String, val age: Int, val count: Int)

val person1 = Person("Jack", 20, listOf(Device("Samsung", 1500), Device("iPhone", 2500)))
val person2 = Person("Jack", 20, listOf(Device("Samsung", 3500), Device("iPhone", 5500)))
val person3 = Person("John", 20, emptyList())
```

The final result should be:

```kotlin
// [PersonFinal(name=Jack, age=20, count=4), PersonFinal(name=John, age=20, count=0)]
```

How can I do this using Kotlin?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Count the number of unique devices or total devices? And if there are multiple people with the same name, what age goes in PersonFinal?

Comment: @matt freake i have not idea, how to do that.

Comment: I guess, i started from `groupBy { it.name }` after that i've got a map of name and list of person by that name.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i need a list of PersonFinal after mapping List<Person> with devices count for person with same name.

Comment: After grouping, use `map` to convert the `Map<String, List<Person>>` entries into a PersonFinal. I guess you're just assuming all people with the same name also have the same age?

Comment: Yes, i'll try it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If someone needed, my final solution looks like:

```
listOf(person1, person2, person3)
        .groupBy { it.name }
        .map { (_, list) -> 
            PersonFinal(list.first().name, list.first().age, list.sumBy { it.devices.count() })
        }
```

Prints `[PersonFinal(name=Jack, age=20, count=4), PersonFinal(name=John, age=20, count=0)]`